# Sign in with Google: PHP fatal error in Idiorm code

Tags: google-api, fatal-error

Sign in with Google isn't working for me. Here is the link to sign into my app: http://hoobi.info/test/

The error message is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name' in /home/content/73/7867073/html/test/includes/idiorm.php:186 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/73/7867073/html/test/includes/idiorm.php(186): PDO->__construct('password', NULL, NULL, Array) #1 /home/content/73/7867073/html/test/includes/idiorm.php(173): ORM::_setup_db() #2 /home/content/73/7867073/html/test/index.php(30): ORM::for_table('glogin_users') #3 {main} thrown in /home/content/73/7867073/html/test/includes/idiorm.php on line 186

I followed this tutorial here: http://tutorialzine.com/2012/08/build-a-one-click-registration-form-powered-by-google/

What can I try next?

Comment: Trying this tutorial right now.  You'd have to explain exactly which step you were on, and what you had done previously.

Comment: As a side note, my create table script doesn't have the 'photo' column.  Any idea what type it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'photo' column missing in database